# Java check if boolean is null

Tags: java, performance, boolean, nullable

How do you check if a boolean is null or not? So if I know `hideInNav` is null. How do I stop
it from further executing? Something like the below doesn't seem to work but why?

```
boolean hideInNav = parent.getProperties().get("hideInNav", false);
String hideNavigation = hideInNav != null ? hideInNav : "";
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`boolean` can only be `true` or `false` because it's a [primitive datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (+ a `boolean` variables default value is `false`). You can use the class `Boolean` instead if you want to use `null` values. Boolean is a reference type, that's the reason you can assign `null` to a Boolean "variable". Example:

```
Boolean testvar = null;
if (testvar == null) { ...}
```

Comment: So could I do something like: **Boolean hideInNav = parent.getProperties().get("hideInNav", false); if(hideInNav != null){ do something } **

Comment: Yes, because then `hideInNav` holds a reference to a `Boolean` object and can be `null` (no reference assigned). Therefor you can check if the reference is `null`.

Comment: BooleanUtils.isTrue(java.lang.Boolean bool) is what I use to check its status in the condition as Boolean can be null.  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.html

Comment: Without apache commons:
```Boolean.TRUE.equals(xxx)```

Answer (score 84):

- A `boolean` cannot be `null` in Java.
- A `Boolean`, however, can be `null`.
- If a `boolean` is not assigned a value (say a *member* of a class)
  then it will be `false` by default.

Comment: Correct Explanation, Thanks.

Comment: for me this is not correct, boolean  is giving null

Comment: @صليعليمحمد-AtefFarouk, then you are either not working with Java or you mistook `Boolean` for `boolean`.

Answer (score 12):

The only thing that can be a `null` is a non-primivite.

A `boolean` which can only hold `TRUE` or `FALSE` is a primitive. The `TRUE`/`FALSE` in memory are actually numbers (`0` and `1`)

> 0 = FALSE
>
> 1 = TRUE

So when you instantiate an object it will be null
`String str; // will equal null`

On the other hand if you instaniate a primitive it will be assigned to 0 default.

`boolean isTrue; // will be 0`

`int i; // will be 0`

Comment: The capitalization of `Boolean` in “A `Boolean` which…” is unfortunate.  A variable of type `boolean` can only hold `true` and `false`, but a variable of type `Boolean` holds a `Boolean` object, or `null`.

Answer (score 8):

`boolean` is a primitive type, and therefore can not be null.

Its boxed type, `Boolean`, can be null.

The function is probably returning a `Boolean` as opposed to a `boolean`, so assigning the result to a `Boolean`-type variable will allow you to test for nullity.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, `null` only applies to object references; since `boolean` is a primitive type, it cannot be assigned `null`.

It's hard to get context from your example, but I'm guessing that if `hideInNav` is not in the object returned by `getProperties()`, the (default value?) you've indicated will be `false`.  I suspect this is the bug that you're seeing, as `false` is not equal to `null`, so `hideNavigation` is getting the empty string?

You might get some better answers with a bit more context to your code sample.

Answer (score 4):

`null` is a value assigned to a reference type. `null` is a reserved value, indicating that a reference does not resemble an instance of an object.

A `boolean` is not an instance of an Object. It is a primitive type, like `int` and `float`. In the same way that: `int x` has a value of `0`, `boolean x` has a value of `false`.

Comment: Agreed. Not the best time for spelling mistakes! Swiftly editing :)

Answer (score 0):

**boolean** is a primitive data type in Java and **primitive data types can not be null like other primitives int, float etc**, they should be containing default values if not assigned.

In Java, only objects can assigned to null, it means the corresponding object has no reference and so does not contain any representation in memory.

Hence If you want to work with object as *null* , you should be using Boolean class which wraps ***a primitive boolean type value*** inside its object.

> These are called wrapper classes in Java

For Example:

```
Boolean bool = readValue(...); // Read Your Value
if (bool  == null) { do This ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Objects.equals()` from `java.util.Objects`

```
if(Objects.equals(value1, value1){
 //your code
}
```

In documentation it said, this will check null and value as well.

Implementation from Java doc:

```
Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false otherwise. 
Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned and if exactly one 
argument is null, false is returned. Otherwise, equality is determined by using 
the equals method of the first argument.

Params: a – an object 
        b – an object to be compared with a for equality
Returns: true if the arguments are equal to each other and false otherwise
See Also: Object.equals(Object)

public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have one or several boolean params in a Maven plugin, which need to be assigned to related class fields. For other @Param fileds I've used !=null condition and tried to found smth for boolean. So, I created an initializeParams() method to assign @Param values to private class fields.
Solved by checking if at least one of non-boolean @Params !=null.
Needed all this to write some unit tests for Java implementation of goals of Maven plugins.